# How can I access jquery Stringified array elements using PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays

I use the following to post to a PHP page, showing the result in the message div:

```
        let x = JSON.stringify($('#my-form').serializeArray());
        $.post("processjs.php", {data:x})

         .done(function(result, status, xhr) {
            $("#message").html(result)
          })
```

That results in the following array:

```
[{"name":"AccountName","value":"TestAcct"},{"name":"AccountID","value":"FR-62"},{"name":"Domain","value":"TestDomain"},{"name":"Status","value":"Enabled"},{"name":"ConfigurationSetName","value":"WLOD-1"},{"name":"SecConfVersion","value":"4"},{"name":"LastUpdated","value":"2022-12-1"},{"name":"MostCurrentVersion","value":"Yes"},{"name":"NotCurrentVersionReason","value":"None"},{"name":"RouterCount","value":"3"},{"name":"CustomerASN","value":"999999"},{"name":"ConfiguredP","value":"127"},{"name":"IPInstalled","value":"No"},{"name":"SharedGroup","value":"True"},{"name":"overlap","value":"False"},{"name":"POverlap","value":"False"},{"name":"ACLSDConfigured","value":"No"},{"name":"ACESDCount","value":"432"}]
```

How can I use PHP to access the array elements?  Why are all of the keys and values prefaced with "name:" or "value:"?

I have tried using the following to access a key:

```
$json = json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['data']),true);
$AccountName = $json['AccountName'];
echo $AccountName;
```

But I always get the same message:

> Undefined array key "AccountName"

I have tried using the following to access a key:

```
$json = json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['data']),true);
$AccountName = $json['AccountName'];
echo $AccountName;
```

I have also tried things like

```
$AccountName = $json[0]['AccountName'];
 or
$AccountName = $json[0];
 and also
$AccountName = $json[1];
```

Comment: *Why are all of the keys and values prefaced with "name:" or "value:"?* - your jquery has converted your form to a name-pair array via your call to `.serializeArray()` - your string is the JSON stringified version of that array.  Shown clearly here: https://api.jquery.com/serializearray/

Comment: Your php will need to read this as a key-value pair.

Comment: `$json[0]['value'];`, next time simple use `print_r` for see the result of your array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your sample request, AccountName is not a index, it is value of name index in a object inside a array.

Please try like this.

```
$json = json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['data']),true);
foreach($json as $inner){
    $name = $inner['name']; //"AccountName" ....  Here you will get value in $name a name .
    $accountId = $inner['value']; //"TestAcct"   ...  Here you will get value in $accountId as "TestAcct" name .
}
```

Outputs are stated only for first iteration of foreach .

Comment: I'm not a php dev, but won't this give `$AccountName` = "AccountName", then "AccountID", then "Domain" as it loops through?  `$inner->value` would give the *value*.  Needs a check that `->name == "AccountName"`.

Comment: Yes, In the first iteration,  $inner->name  will be "AccountName" and $inner->value will be "TestAcct"

Comment: It will go through till all the objects are not completed from the array.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to respond, @Satyandra.  When implemented as described, I receive the following: 
Warning: Attempt to read property "name" on array in /opt/homebrew/var/www/soa/processjs.php on line 35

Warning: Attempt to read property "name" on array in /opt/homebrew/var/www/soa/processjs.php on line 35

Warning: Attempt to read property "name" on array in /opt/homebrew/var/www/soa/processjs.php on line 35

Warning: Attempt to read property "name" on array in /opt/homebrew/var/www/soa/processjs.php on line 35

Comment: ok, you can change object accessibility to array index. Like $name = $inner->name; to $name = $inner['name']; $accountId = $inner['value'];

Comment: Updated the answer as well .

Comment: Your last edit now reveals the array elements to me.  Thank you very much and have a wonderful weekend!